# searchBarSearchButtonClicked not firing

Tags: uisearchbar, uisearchbardelegate

I have researched this question. Looks like this is a common question but nothing I have tried has worked. I am very new to iPhone app development and Objective C. All I want to do at this point is type in a string in a search bar field and return the value in NSLog() when the Search button on the keypad is tapped.

My header file looks like this:

```
@interface ListingMapViewController : UIViewController <UISearchBarDelegate> 

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;

@end
```

I have this in my class file:

```
#import "ListingMapViewController.h"

@interface ListingMapViewController ()


@end

@implementation ListingMapViewController


- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
searchBar.delegate =self;

[self handleSearch:searchBar];
NSLog(@"User searched for %@", searchBar.text);

}

@end
```

When I click the Search button nothing outputs. What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Search information about how to use delegate

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableSearch/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 6):

(Answered in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> Solved this by setting the searchBar delegate when the view loads. I guess setting it in `searchBarSearchButtonClicked` is too late.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
[self.searchBar setDelegate:self];
 //self.searchBar.delegate = self; <-- also works
}
```

> Now when I click the Search button on the keypad the text in the search bar field outputs to `NSLog()`. Hurray! On to the next challenge.